# Unable to modify file path

Tags: python-3.x, path

[**File not found error when the file exists**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRmR.png)

I keep receiving the file not found error when I try to do this even when the file exists
please is there an explanation as to why this is happening and what can I do to fix this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and error as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.